# Uploading PDF files to Server in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, file-upload, web

i have a web based application i need to add new featuer is to upload PDF files from DVD to folder location in a server.

the DVD structer like this
1- Folder 12072013
2- in the same level there is CSV file and Folder called Images.

i need to upload the data in the CSV file which is done, and i need to upload the PDF files
insid the Images folder also, Copy it from the DVD to Folder in the server.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal SourcePath As String, ByVal DestPath As String, Optional ByVal Overwrite As Boolean = True)
    Application.DoEvents()
    Dim SourceDir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(SourcePath)
    Dim DestDir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(DestPath)

    ' the source directory must exist, otherwise throw an exception
    If SourceDir.Exists Then
        ' if destination SubDir's parent SubDir does not exist throw an exception
        If Not DestDir.Parent.Exists Then
            Throw New DirectoryNotFoundException _
                ("Destination directory does not exist: " + DestDir.Parent.FullName)
        End If

        If Not DestDir.Exists Then
            DestDir.Create()
        End If

        ' copy all the files of the current directory
        Dim ChildFile As FileInfo
        For Each ChildFile In SourceDir.GetFiles()
            If Overwrite Then
                ChildFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(DestDir.FullName, ChildFile.Name), True)
            Else
                If Not File.Exists(Path.Combine(DestDir.FullName, ChildFile.Name)) Then
                    ChildFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(DestDir.FullName, ChildFile.Name), False)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        ' copy all the sub-directories by5 recursively calling this same routine
        Dim SubDir As DirectoryInfo
        For Each SubDir In SourceDir.GetDirectories()
            CopyDirectory(SubDir.FullName, Path.Combine(DestDir.FullName, _
                SubDir.Name), Overwrite)
        Next
    Else
        Throw New DirectoryNotFoundException("Source directory does not exist: " + SourceDir.FullName)
    End If
End Sub
```